# Windows azure with error Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.FileStore

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

After I updated Azure SDK to 1.7 version and tried to publish my changes on web role it shows me an error:

```
Windows Azure could not find the resource Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.FileStore in the service package.
```

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure in your SDK 1.7 based application you have the following setting in CSDEF:

```
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.FileStore" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
</LocalResources>
```

Based on this error, I can see that you are updating the previous SDK 1.6 based deployment which does not have above setting and that why you are getting this error.

Because your configuration is changed update is failing. As a workaround to this problem, you can do a fresh new deployment to your Staging slot first and then SWAP VIP with production to have it updated.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem. The problem was because settings for co-locate cache in this key
name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ConfigStoreConnectionString" was set to development store, not to real blob storage. It was the problem